# Formula to get a specific value in string between periods

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, substitution

AAAAAAAAAAA.BBB.CCCC.DD.EEEEEE.F.G.

Note the lengths will vary for each value between periods. I need to return just the value of G in this string. G will sometimes be two digits and sometimes one digit. It will always have a period at the end and the string will be terminated after the period.

Comment: Wil the other sections be of the same length? or variable length?

Comment: Everything is variable length. That was the first sentence @Dane. Thanks for helping everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,3),".","")
```